# How do I insert rows of data after a specific row in Google Spreadsheets via the v4 API?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I understand that using `append`, I can add rows of data to the bottom of the table. However, what I'd really like to do is to add rows of data at exactly row 2 (ie one row below my header row).

Is this possible? I have read through the `append` method but do not see a clear way to do this. Is there another method I should be using?

(https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`spreadsheets.values.update`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), as stated in the document:

> It is possible, when writing values to a range, to avoid changing some of the existing cells by setting the corresponding array elements to `null`. It is also possible to clear a cell by writing an empty string to it.

Here is a code snippet from the document:

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!B1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED

{
  "range": "Sheet1!B1",
  "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
  "values": [
    [null,"$1","$2", ""],
    [],
    [null,"4/1/2016", "4/15/2016", ""]
  ]
}
```

> The **values** field here lists the changes made to each column in the range. The first array indicates that B1 is to be left unchanged (due to the **`null`** array element), while B4 is to be cleared (empty string). B2 and B3 have their values updated. The third array performs the same operations on column D, while the second empty array indicates that column C is to be left unchanged.

Hope this helps.